# Reading stdin as binary file in windows python3

Tags: windows, python-3.x, stdin, file-handling

I have a code to read stdin as binary file in linux:

```
#! /usr/bin/python3
stdin_file = '/dev/stdin'
def read_input():
    with open(stdin_file, mode='rb') as f:
        while True:
            inp = f.read(4)
            if not inp: break
            print('got :' , inp)

read_input()
```

what could be its alternative for windows OS?
I dont want to use `sys.stdin.buffer.read()`
Consider it as it is compulsary for me to use it like `open(file_name)`

Answer (score 2):

`sys.stdin`, `sys.stdout`, and `sys.stderr` each have a `fileno()` method which returns their file descriptor number. (0, 1, or 2).

In python you can use the buffer's `fileno` as the path destination for `open`.

Also, as [@Eryk Sun](https://stackoverflow.com/users/205580/eryk-sun) mentioned in a comment, you probably want to pass `closefd=False` when calling `open` so the underlying file descriptor for `sys.stdin` isn't closed when exiting the `with` block.

For example:

```
import sys

fileno = sys.stdin.fileno()
print(fileno)
# prints 0

# Open stdin's file descriptor number as a file.
with open(fileno, "rb", closefd=False) as f:
    while True:
        inp = f.read(4)
        if not inp:
            break
        print("Got:", inp)
```

Comment: Do remember to call `fileno` instead of hard-coding the fd value. It's not necessarily 0. `sys.stdin` may have been reassigned, and there can be other reasons that `stdin` isn't fd 0.

Answer (score 0):

Even though you said in your question "I dont want to use `sys.stdin.buffer.read()`", this might be useful for other users coming to this answer..

A good option is to use the `.buffer` member of the stream to get access to a binary version:

```
stdin_buffer = sys.stdin.buffer
def read_input():
    while True:
        inp = stdin_buffer.read(4)
        if not inp: break
        print('got :' , inp)
```